# Laravel Trying to get property 'name' of non-object with relation and query

Tags: php, laravel

When I am trying to query with relation in following way, I am getting error *Trying to get property 'name' of non-object*

```
$billing = ServiceProviderBilling::with(['user' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('parent_id', auth()->id());
        }])->get();
```

There is no error if I use

```
$billing = ServiceProviderBilling::with(['user'])->get();
```

In my view

```
@foreach($billing as $bill)
    {{ $bill->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Relations

```
public function serviceProviderBillings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ServiceProviderBilling::class);
    }
```

and

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It means $bill->user return null. some bill has no user

Comment: Yes, its returning null. I checked with dd

Comment: do u want to show the bill without user?

Comment: no, but actually all the users has billing in my db. I fixed foreign key in relation. same result. withdefault() is giving another error

Comment: if all the bills has user, plz post the relationship method code. Or you can try `ServiceProviderBilling::whereDoesntHave('user')->get()` to find out those bills without user

Comment: relationships added

Comment: user has many bills, and the foriegn_key of bill is `user_id`, and the primary_key of user is `id`? have u try `ServiceProviderBilling::whereDoesntHave('user')->get()`

Comment: Just tried as you said. It cannot resolve the query. Error *Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on array *

Comment: It seems you are applying `whereDoesntHave('user')` to array.

Comment: Required some modification but it works. `ServiceProviderBilling::with('user')->whereHas('user', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('parent_id', auth()->id());
        })->get();`

Comment: @TsaiKoga Please post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means $bill->user return null. some bill has no user, If you want show the bills without user, you can use `whereHas` method:

```php
ServiceProviderBilling::with('user')
                      ->whereHas('user', function (Builder $query) { 
                          $query->where('parent_id', auth()->id()); 
                      })->get()
```